# Rviz2 high CPU usage on Ubuntu Server

Tags: rviz, ros-humble, docker, cpu

Running Rviz2 in Docker using Ubuntu server (22.04.3 LTS) shows a high CPU usage.
Running the same docker container on a desktop using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS shows very different results. No topics were subscribed to in both instances. ROS2 distro is Humble.

- Desktop CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core Processor
- Server CPU: AMD EPYC 7313P 16-Core Processor

While I am not observing any performance issues by running rviz2 on the server, I want to make sure that the CPU usage is "ok"/as expected, as it will be prone to more CPU load in the future from running other software.

4 screenshots are attached:

1. htop on desktop
2. htop on server
3. system monitor on desktop
4. system monitor on server

[image: htop Rviz2 on desktop]

[image: htop Rviz2 on server]

[image: System monitor on desktop]

[image: System monitor on server]

Comment: Perhaps you should submit this as an issue in the rviz github.  https://github.com/ros2/rviz/issues

Comment: Thanks @Ben. I will submit this issue.